# How can I access object dynamically in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access the object dynamically based on the ng-click.I will have lot's of form with button like this.

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="news" ng-click="home.addnew()">Update</button>
<button type="button" id="allocation" ng-click="home.addnew()">Update</button>
<button type="button" id="create" ng-click="home.addnew()">Update</button>
```

My Object

```
"home": {
    "news": [{
        "type": "cd",
        "title": "title1",
    }],
    "allocation": [{
        "type": "cd",
        "title": "title2",
    }],
        "create": [{
        "type": "cd",
        "title": "title3",
    }]
    .......etc
}
```

Angularjs Controller

```
$scope.home.addnew = function(){
    var type = $(event.target).attr("id");
       $scope.home.news.title; // Here how can I access that "news","allocation","create" Dynamically
       $scope.home.type.title // I have tried like this 
}
```

I am getting error

```
Cannot read property 'title ' of undefined
```

Comment: Is $scope.home assigned the above json object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trying to access object property instead of array.

It should look like this

```
$scope.home.addnew = function(){
    var type = $(event.target).attr("id");
    $scope.home[type][0].title; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have attached home to $scope as one of the user already commented. $scope.home needs to exist before you start working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use brackets for array

```
 var dynamicType ='news'; 
                var obj ={"home": {
                "news": [{
                "type": "cd",
                "title": "title1",
                }],
                "allocation": [{
                "type": "cd",
                "title": "title2",
                }],
                "create": [{
                "type": "cd",
                "title": "title3",
                }]
            }};
    console.log(obj.home[dynamicType][0].title);
```